Extract data from array Python (spotify API)
Fairly simple question.
How to extract the spotify:artist: values from this return data?

[{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4RB42AM4VqzdHRQiVbzDU1'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4RB42AM4VqzdHRQiVbzDU1', 'id': '4RB42AM4VqzdHRQiVbzDU1', 'name': 'Ismailovic', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4RB42AM4VqzdHRQiVbzDU1'}, {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6n18eBRlVxd4v4YnbbYlvs'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6n18eBRlVxd4v4YnbbYlvs', 'id': '6n18eBRlVxd4v4YnbbYlvs', 'name': 'Nabil Sansi', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6n18eBRlVxd4v4YnbbYlvs'}, {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Bv3GYUzNM11yYGQslJOkp'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Bv3GYUzNM11yYGQslJOkp', 'id': '4Bv3GYUzNM11yYGQslJOkp', 'name': 'Mr. ID', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4Bv3GYUzNM11yYGQslJOkp'}]

artists_id is the data, I tried:
print(artists_id[spotify:artist])
I expect [4RB42AM4VqzdHRQiVbzDU1] [6n18eBRlVxd4v4YnbbYlvs] [4Bv3GYUzNM11yYGQslJOkp].

You have a list of dictionaries. For each dictionary you're interested in the values associated with the "id" key.
Therefore:
data = [
    {
        "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4RB42AM4VqzdHRQiVbzDU1"
        },
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4RB42AM4VqzdHRQiVbzDU1",
        "id": "4RB42AM4VqzdHRQiVbzDU1",
        "name": "Ismailovic",
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:4RB42AM4VqzdHRQiVbzDU1",
    },
    {
        "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6n18eBRlVxd4v4YnbbYlvs"
        },
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6n18eBRlVxd4v4YnbbYlvs",
        "id": "6n18eBRlVxd4v4YnbbYlvs",
        "name": "Nabil Sansi",
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:6n18eBRlVxd4v4YnbbYlvs",
    },
    {
        "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Bv3GYUzNM11yYGQslJOkp"
        },
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Bv3GYUzNM11yYGQslJOkp",
        "id": "4Bv3GYUzNM11yYGQslJOkp",
        "name": "Mr. ID",
        "type": "artist",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:4Bv3GYUzNM11yYGQslJOkp",
    },
]

print(*[f"[{d['id']}]" for d in data])

Output:
[4RB42AM4VqzdHRQiVbzDU1] [6n18eBRlVxd4v4YnbbYlvs] [4Bv3GYUzNM11yYGQslJOkp]

